# Limiting checked items of TCheckListBox on Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, checklistbox, tchecklistbox

I want to limit a TCheckListBox.
I desire only 2 items should be checked, and all unchecked items will be disabled and grayed.
Since the checked / unchecked items are dynamic, i can not use a static itemIndex.

Here is what i tried, but i got "Out of chip bounds" error.

On click event of my CheckListBox ;

```
var
  NumberOfCheckedItems, I: Integer;
begin
  NumberOfCheckedItems := 0;
  for I := 0 to CkLst1.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if CkLst1.Checked[I] then
      NumberOfCheckedItems := NumberOfCheckedItems + 1;
  end;
  if NumberOfCheckedItems > 1 then
  begin
    CkLst1.Checked[I] := Enabled;
    CkLst1.Enabled := FALSE;
    CkLst1.AllowGrayed := TRUE;
  end
  else
  begin
    //no idea
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You must not use uninitialized `I` after the loop, because `I` has to be treatend as uninitialized after the loop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This method should do the job

```
procedure DoCheckListBox( AChkLb : TCheckListBox; AMaxCheck : Integer );
var
  LIdx : Integer;
  LCheckCount : Integer;
begin
  // counting
  LCheckCount := 0;
  for LIdx := 0 to AChkLb.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if AChkLb.Checked[LIdx] then
      if LCheckCount = AMaxCheck then
        AChkLb.Checked[LIdx] := False
      else
        Inc( LCheckCount );
  end;
  // enable/disable
  for LIdx := 0 to AChkLb.Count - 1 do
    AChkLb.ItemEnabled[LIdx] := AChkLb.Checked[LIdx] or ( LCheckCount < AMaxCheck );
end;
```

**UPDATE**

You better call this inside [`TCheckListBox.OnClickCheck`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/CheckLst.TCheckListBox.OnClickCheck) event instead of `OnClick` event.
A double-click can affect the check-state but `OnClick` is not called.
`OnClickCheck` is called whenever the check-state changes.

Comment: Awesome ! This is exactly what i want. Much appreciate this. Thank you.

Comment: Please have a look at the update to avoid unwanted side effects

Comment: Aha, i just noticed this could trigger accidentally double click. Will put this OnClickCheck event now. Thanks again.